# mysqli_fetch_assoc() function not working

Tags: php

```
<?php
    define('HOST','host');
    define('USER','user name');
    define('PASS','password');
    define('DB','db name');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
    $sql = "select * from toursit_guide where cat='Amusement Parks'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $json = array();

    if($rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {
    echo $rowcount;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $json['tourist_guide'][]=$row;
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($json,JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR); 
?>
```

This code worked fine in Hostinger, but when I migrate to Godaddy it isn't working (getting no output)

This code is working fine with Godaddy:

```
<?php

define('HOST','hostname');

define('USER','username');

define('PASS','password');

define('DB','db_name');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$sql = "select * from vg_main";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
array_push($result,

array('id'=>$row[0],

'cat_name'=>$row[1],
'sub_cat_name'=>$row[2],
'name'=>$row[3],
'icon'=>$row[4],
'description'=>$row[5],
'lat'=>$row[6],
'lon'=>$row[7],
'contact_no'=>$row[8],
'email_id'=>$row[9],
'website'=>$row[10],
'open_time'=>$row[12],
'Address'=>$row[13],
'image'=>$row[14]

));

}
echo json_encode(array("Output"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I want to do it with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` as many files are written with assoc.

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){$result[] = $row;}` and then print it `echo "<pre/>";print_r($result);` and check something is coming or not?

Comment: Check for errors with [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and check the error log.

Comment: mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 15
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 5
    [type] => 0
)This output i got

Comment: Thanks Anant its working now, your solution worked for me